# Swap faces by binary masks

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection

I have 2 kinds of portrait images: usual people (call it source) and people with blurred faces. Also I have facemasks for both of image groups. I want to put faces from the source images to blurred. If I had non-blurred faces I would be able to use OpenCV+Dlib for landmark detection and remapping triangles then. Is it possible to somehow remap source face to blurred? Accuracy is not important, it's only important to get rid of blurred part with similar to real world data. Attached examples of images from 2 groups.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: so you need to estimate the pose of a head with the face blurred out... good luck. all the crucial landmarks are on the face. the rest of the head has next to no usable landmarks. the best you can do is input a plausible head pose manually, then render the face overlay, and assess whether that looks natural, and maybe adjust the assumed head pose until it looks plausible

Comment: it could reformulated like: how to remap one binary mask to another? I understand situation about landmarks, so imagine you dont know what kind of data is under these masks

Comment: actually, no, if you just "remapped one binary mask to another", the face wouldn't match the head at all. this can't possibly be what you want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZUpu.png

Comment: maybe you want AI inpainting... but that's not a programming problem. that just requires you to play with publicly available models... and that is asking for recommendations.

Comment: i think its enough accurate for my problem. Can you share the solution please?

Comment: I did that manually in a photo editor because you failed to provide the mask.

Comment: Sorry, updated question with facemasks